# How does one access ViewState from within a shared class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote some web pages that use common routines that required ViewState values.

Can the ViewState be passed into the functions?

If so, how?

If not, how else can I access them from a method in a class?

Comment: You could pass the `Page` instance or probably better, just the relevant values which you've already extracted from the `ViewState` before you call them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key statement:

> common routines that required ViewState values

But functions don't really require "ViewState" values - they just require values. If a function operates on a `string` or an `int` then it's better to write the function that way, which makes it easier to unit test.

If it's a number of very specific values that you want to read and/or manipulate then you could create a class like this:

```
public class MyPageValues
{
    public string Value1 {get;set;}
    public string Value2 {get;set;}
}
```

and then add a constructor or extension method that loads the values from `ViewState`.

```
public class MyPageValues
{
    public string Value1 {get;set;}
    public string Value2 {get;set;}

    public MyPageValues(){} //default constructor
    public MyPageValues(System.Web.UI.StateBag viewState)
    {
        Value1 = (string)viewState["Value1"];
        Value2 = integer.Parse(viewState["Value2"]); //Do some better checking.
    }
}
```

Better yet, just serialize the whole class into viewstate and retrieve it from there.

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyValues
{
    public string Value1 {get;set;}
    public string Value2 {get;set;}
}

public partial class YourPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MyValues _values;

    protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        _values = ViewState["myValues"] as MyValues ?? new MyValues ();
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["myValues"] = _values;
    }
}
```

That way you can extract the class from `ViewState` at `Page_Load` (or create a new instance if needed), read it, manipulate it, pass it to other functions, and then when you're done you just save the whole thing intact back to `ViewState`.